# Syntax Error in Yaml File - missed comma between flow collection entries

Tags: kubernetes, syntax, yaml, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

We have an application deployed in AKS , the kubernetes version we were using is 1.15 now we want to upgrade the Kubernetes to 1.16, I notice that some of the APIs have been deprecated in 1.16.We have deployment.yaml file in which I had to change the from

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1 to apiVersion: apps/v1 for Deployment.

after doing this change I see that the deployment YAML is failing lint test for another entry :

```
    - name  : APP_HOST
    {{- range $host := .Values.ingress.hosts }}
      value: {{ $host }}
    {{- end }}
```

Error :

npx yaml-lint yamllint deployment.yaml

npx: installed 45 in 14.04s

× YAML Lint failed for deployment.yaml

× missed comma between flow collection entries at line 88, column 11:
{{- range $host := .Values.ingress ...

Can some one help me with the syntax needed for this. Mind you it was working fine before. Not sure if I have  added and extra space or corrupted the file.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you have looks like a correct Helm template, including correct whitespace controls.  However, it is *not* valid YAML; the template `{{ ... }}` syntax looks at least a little bit like an inline mapping `{ key: value }`, and this confuses the linter.

You can't run the un-rendered Helm template files through `yamllint` or another plain YAML validator.  You can run `helm template` to render the template to plain text, and then run `yamllint` on that.  The current version of Helm will try to parse the produced YAML as it generates it, so just running `helm template` will give you some protection against whitespace errors.